# How do I launch the Selenium IDE from the terminal with a specific test case loaded?

Tags: firefox, selenium

I've got as far as:

```
firefox -chrome chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-ide.xul
```

which launches the IDE, but I don't know how to launch the Selenium IDE with a specific test case loaded?

for Windows, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144744/how-do-i-launch-the-selenium-ide-from-the-command-line-with-a-specific-test-case)

Comment: I never used selenium IDE.  I have, however, used it with nightwatchjs and the python-selenium harness.  You might want to look in to those as toolsets.

Comment: It probably uses the same command line arguments as on Windows.